# Computing residue fields of affine schemes

Tags: schemes, localization, affine-schemes, local-rings

I have taken a course on schemes, so I am familiar with the basic definitions, but I'm very rusty and I've forgotten how to do this (if I ever knew).

Basically, I want to compute the residue fields of points on affine schemes like
$$
X = \operatorname{Spec}\Big(\frac{\mathbb{F}_p[x, y]}{(x^2 + y^2)}\Big).
$$
For example, I'd like to compute the residue field of $X$ at the point $(0,0)$, by which I mean the prime ideal $(x, y)$. Algebraically, I want to compute the residue field of the local ring
$$
\Big( \frac{\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]}{(x^2 + y^2)}\Big)_\mathfrak{m},
$$
where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the (maximal) ideal generated by $x$ and $y$. This seems like a bit of a nightmare to do by hand, but I suspect there's some geometric machinery that can deal with it quite easily.

Comment: You can skip the localization and just directly mod out $(x,y)$ in the original ring, which you may find easier to think about.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah right, so for any $\mathbb{F}_p$-point $(a,b)$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]/I)$, we have that $(\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]/I) / ((x - a, x - y)/I) \cong \mathbb{F}_p$, so the localisation is just the same field again.

Answer (score 1):

A useful fact here is that if $A$ is a commutative ring and $P\subset A$ is a prime ideal, then the residue field of the localization $A_P$ is naturally isomorphic to the field of fractions of the quotient $A/P$.  (Basically, to get the residue field, you need to kill $P$ and invert each element of $A\setminus P$, and it doesn't matter which order you do these two steps in.)  In the case of a maximal ideal, the residue field of the localization is just the same as the quotient $A/P$.  So in your case, instead of having to worry about what your localization looks like, you can just mod $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ out by the ideal $(x,y)$, which just gives you $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]/(x,y)\cong \mathbb{F}_p$.